# Limits : solving indeterminate form

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Hey can someone help in working out the right hand limit. The curly brackets indicate fractional part

$$\lim_{n\to0^+}\bigg(\frac {(1+\left\{n\right\})^{\frac {1}{\left\{n\right\}}}}{e}\bigg)^{\frac {1}{\left\{n\right\}}}$$

I am having a confusion that the quantity inside the bracket is tending to 1 but whatever it be, it will always be less than 1 ( I analysed and found that the derivative at x =0+ is negative) , thus anything less than 1raised to the power infinity is 0 , but the answer is coming different , pls enlighten and clarify my doubt

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59772/discussion-on-question-by-user353587-limits-solving-indeterminate-form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the "fractional function" matters, especially as we are approaching zero, where everything is only a "fraction"
$$\lim _{n \to 0} \left(\frac{(1+n)^{1/n}}{e}\right)^{1/n} = L \approx6.066...\text{ according to Wolfram Alpha}$$

$$\lim _{n \to 0} \left(\frac{1}{n}*\ln\frac{(1+n)^{1/n}}{e}\right) = \ln L$$
$$\lim _{n \to 0} \left(\frac{1}{n}* \left( \ln\frac{(1+n)^{1/n}}{e}\right)\right) = \lim _{n \to 0} \left(\frac{1}{n}*(\ln(1+n)^{1/n} - \ln(e))\right)$$
$$\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{1}{n}*\ln\left((1+n)^{1/n}\right) - \frac{1}{n}*1 = \lim_{n \to 0} \frac{1}{n^2}*\ln(1+n) - \frac{1}{n}$$

Using the MacLaurin series for $ln(1+n) = n - n^2/2 + n^3/3 -n^4/4 ...$

$$\lim_{n \to 0} \frac{1}{n^2}*(n - n^2/2 + n^3/3 - n^4/4 ...) - \frac{1}{n} = \lim_{n \to 0} 1/n - 1/2 + n/3 - n^2/4 + n^3/5 .. - 1/n$$

And at $0$ all of the terms with $n$ will become $0$ and $1/n$ cancels leaving us with

$$-1/2 = \ln L $$
$$ L = e^{-1/2} = 0.60653065$$

Comment: I guess there is a typo 6.066 by wolfram alpha should be 0.6065...

Comment: @John Lou , thanks,  I also got the same result, but my confusion was when I checked the graph of (1+x)^(1/x) then the limit approaching  0 from the right side was was coming out to be less than e , see here https://www.graphsketch.com/?eqn1_color=1&eqn1_eqn=(1%2Bx)%5E(1%2Fx)&eqn2_color=2&eqn2_eqn=&eqn3_color=3&eqn3_eqn=&eqn4_color=4&eqn4_eqn=&eqn5_color=5&eqn5_eqn=&eqn6_color=6&eqn6_eqn=&x_min=-17&x_max=17&y_min=-10.5&y_max=10.5&x_tick=1&y_tick=1&x_label_freq=5&y_label_freq=5&do_grid=0&do_grid=1&bold_labeled_lines=0&bold_labeled_lines=1&line_width=4&image_w=850&image_h=525

Comment: So the value of the expression inside the parenthesis would be although tending to one but always less than one , and it is raised to the power tending to infinity, then , anything less than one raised to the power infinity is 0 , so that's the  confusion i had .pls clarify if i am wrong in my thought process

Comment: Unfortunately, that argument is flawed, as you can't take the limit inside first in this situation. See an easier example:

$$\lim{x \to 0}(1-x)^{1/x} = e^{-1}$$

Using the incorrect observation, this would be zero
This case is easily proven by taking the substitution $u = -x$

$$\lim_{x \to 0} = \lim_{u \to 0} (1+u)^{-1/u} = \frac{1}{(1+u)^{1/u}}$$